# If conditional tree to switch statement efficiency troubles

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, switch-statement

I've been trying to optimize functions with long series of if statements. I'd though I'd found a solution using switch statements as a replacement, but upon testing and disassembly, I found out that they just complicated the matter.
Heres some code to demonstrate;

```
 int ifFunc(int A, int B, int C){
   int ret;
   if (A > 0){
     if (B > 0){
       if (C > 0){
         ret = C;
       }
       else{
         ret = B;
       }
     }
     else{
       if(C > 0){
         ret = C;
       }
       else{
         ret = A;
       }
     }
   }
   else{
     if (B > 0){
       if (C > 0){
         ret = C;
       }
       else{
         ret = B;
       }
     }
     else{
       if (C > 0){
         ret = C;
       }
       else{
         ret = 0;
       }
     }
   }
   return ret;
 }

 int swFunc(int A, int B, int C){
   int ret; int code = 0;
   code += (A > 0) * 4, code += (B > 0) * 2, code += (C > 0) * 1;
   switch(code){
   case 0: // 000
     ret = 0;
     break;
   case 1: // 001
     ret = C;
     break;
   case 2: // 010
     ret = B;
     break;
   case 3: // 011
     ret = C;
     break;
   case 4: // 100
     ret = A;
     break;
   case 5: // 101
     ret = C;
     break;
   case 6: // 110
     ret = B;
     break;
   case 7: // 111
     ret = C;
     break;
   }
   return ret;
 }
 // All these functions do is select a number that is positive,
 // Giving preference to C, then B, then A
```

I may have made a few mistakes, so they might not be doing exactly the same thing, but that's beside the point. What I was trying to do with the switch statement was create a version of ifFunc with only a single jump, by converting the result of each if statement into a numerical code that would align with a bit, so that each possible end point would have a unique numerical code.

This falls flat however, as the comparison functions (B > 0) etc. internally utilize jumps. It ends up with the switch version of the function being an order of magnitude slower then the if version.

I'd like to know if there is anyway to do a comparison statement, and have it output a zero for false and a one for true, without using (internally or otherwise) an if statement or a jump.

Comment: Is that your real use case, or just a demonstration to explain your question?

Comment: Just a demo, though I used the same code for speed testing

Comment: If you are so concerned about jumps, why use a switch, it often becomes a jump.  Use lookup tables.

Comment: As far as I know, if you have no default case, and all your cases form a continuous spectrum, there should only be one or two jumps which should be better once you reach three nested if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it will be much better, but you could try playing with bitfields:

```
union SOMECONDTIONS {
  unsigned char aggregate;
  struct {
    int c1:1;
    int c2:1;
    int c3:1;
    int c4:1;
    int c5:1;
    int c6:1;
    int c7:1;
    int c8:1;
  } conditions;
}

SOMECODITIONS c;
c.aggregate = 0;
c.conditions.c1 = A > 0;
c.conditions.c2 = B > 0;
c.conditions.c3 = C > 0;
switch(c.aggregate) {
...
```

Comment: I'll quickly test and disassemble it and see how it gets handled

Comment: Interestingly, the jumps appear to have disappeared

Comment: Very interest, that actually removed the jumps, and managed to improve performance of my switch solution by an order of magnitude, though if statements still seem to be the way to go. I'll have to play around with this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Might I ask though how you knew that the jumps would be replaced?

Comment: That's because your solution uses conditions in an if statement. This version uses "conditions" to set values. BTW, the best improvement to your code would be to reverse the order in your if version. If you want to return C if it's valid, test that first. Than B, and only Than A. You're working too hard since your tests are backwards

Answer (score 4):

I hope this code will help you to remove jumps in assembly...

```
static const int index[8] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3};

int ifFunc(int a, int b, int c)
{
    const int ret[4] = {0, a, b, c};
    const int bits = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;
    //const int i = ((((c - 1) >> bits) + 1) * 4) +
    //              ((((b - 1) >> bits) + 1) * 2) +
    //               (((a - 1) >> bits) + 1);
    const int i = ((-c >> bits) * -4) -
                  ((-b >> bits) *  2) -
                   (-a >> bits);

    return ret[index[i]];
}
```

Comment: It does! It also produces a very compact disassembly! I going to have to experiment, but I think your solution will be the basis for a proper solution to this issue. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: A simple and elegant code, but it has a little flaw: for a parameter with the smallest possible `int` value, binary `1000...0` (often available as `INT_MIN` constant) subtracting `1` yields a positive result, so the corresponding bit in `i` will be set to `0` instead of `1` – that specific negative parameter value will be handled like it was positive.

Comment: @CiaPan Nice point! Subtracting 1 is to remove 0 from the candidates because of the inequality in condition. However, negation can remove the flaw at the boundary case.  
`
    const int i = ((-c >> bits) * -4) -
                  ((-b >> bits) *  2) -
                   (-a >> bits);
`

Comment: @MK.Lee But you can't negate. For two's complement, if a parameter, say `A`, is binary `1000...0` (for 32-bits integer it is `-2147483648`), then `-A` is not representable, as `INT_MAX == 2147483647`.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly this will do...?

```
int ifFunc(int A, int B, int C){
  if( C > 0 ) return C;
  if( B > 0 ) return B;
  if( A > 0 ) return A;
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I must have misunderstood you—I thought you just need to reduce the number of conditional branches, not to remove them completely. Here's the solution (unless I made some mistake...), based on the assumption your system works in [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) code:

```
static const unsigned iMIN = ~(~0u >> 1);  // binary 1000...0
static const int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;

static inline int partialmask( int x ) {
    // returns positive (0....) for positive x,
    // negative (1....) for negative or zero x
    return x | (int)(iMIN - (unsigned)x);
}
static inline int fullmask( int x ) {
    // extends the sign bit so that
    // positive becomes binary 0000...0 for positive x
    // negative becomes binary 1111...1 for negative or zero x
    return partialmask( x ) >> (BITS_PER_BYTE * sizeof(int) - 1);
}

int noIfFunc(int A, int B, int C){
  int res = 0, mask;

  mask = fullmask( A );  // negative or zero A causes an all-ones mask
  res &= mask;           // to preserve the res value
  res |= A & ~mask;      // and keep it from overwriting with A

  mask = fullmask( B );  // positive B causes
  res &= mask;           // res to be cleared with all-zeros mask
  res |= B & ~mask;      // then overwritten with B

  mask = fullmask( C );
  res &= mask;
  res |= C & ~mask;

  return res;  // finally res == most recent positive value (else zero)
}
```

Probably that's not the shortest possible code. However, it should contain no branches, if properly reduced (with functions inlined).

Comment: I have trouble believing it's the same code... Why the `if`/`else`/`if` madness ? :|

Comment: I am afraid that that the disassembly of that code appears to contain ten+ jumps, which is what i was trying to avoid

Comment: @user4578093 I count [two](http://goo.gl/Z7nbJy). Which compiler are you using that generates a dozen jumps for such a simple function ?

Comment: g++, and fourteen specifically

Comment: I think it is because the compiler wanted a single return, so it transformed it into a nested version

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll need sometime to go through it

Comment: That was incredibly interesting to work through! I'll remember this technique. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
if (C > 0) return C;
if (B > 0) return B;
if (A > 0) return A;
return 0;
```

or

```
return C > 0 ? C : (B > 0 ? B : (A > 0 ? A : 0)));
```

?

Also, if the compiler implements conditional assignments,

```
R= 0;
if (A > 0) R= A;
if (B > 0) R= B;
if (C > 0) R= C;
```

---

In the last case, MSVC does use conditional assignments, but for the third one, as it prefers to return the zeroed register :(

```
; 7    :     int R= 0;
; 8    :     if (A > 0) R= A;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _A$[esp-4]
    xor eax, eax
    test    ecx, ecx
    cmovg   eax, ecx

; 9    :     if (B > 0) R= B;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _B$[esp-4]
    test    ecx, ecx
    cmovg   eax, ecx

; 10   :     if (C > 0) R= C;

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _C$[esp-4]
    test    ecx, ecx
    jle SHORT $LN1@f1

; 12   :    return R;

    mov eax, ecx
$LN1@f1:

    ret 0
```

Comment: That compiles with branches/jumps, which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Maybe, but this code is similar to short-circuit evaluation and should be even better than the nested-if solution. Some compilers should be able to turn the second construct into conditional assignments.

Comment: Interestingly, the second version generated a single conditional, and two jumps like this (I hope the formatting isn't too awful)
int ret = (C > 0 ? C : (B > 0 ? B : (A > 0 ? A : 0)));   cmpl   $0x0,0x10(%ebp)   jg     0x4016f2 <myFunc2(int, int, int)+38>   cmpl   $0x0,0xc(%ebp)   jg     0x4016ed <myFunc2(int, int, int)+33>   mov    $0x0,%eax   cmpl   $0x0,0x8(%ebp)   cmovns 0x8(%ebp),%eax   jmp    0x4016f5 <myFunc2(int, int, int)+41>   mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax   jmp    0x4016f5 <myFunc2(int, int, int)+41>   mov    0x10(%ebp),%eax   mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)

Comment: And of course it was. Anyway, in the middle of that mess is CMOVNS which I believe is Move If SF==0. The third version didn't generate any conditionals for me, and neither did the first, would optimization level have anything to do with this? I compiled with g++ -std=c++11 -g

Comment: Now only benchmarking can tell what is better (if there's any answer to this).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that nearly beats the compiler's version using inline assembly. My apologies if it's a little off, I only learned assembly last night

```
 int swFunc(int A, int B, int C){
   int ret; char code;
   //code += (A > 0) * 4, code += (B > 0) * 2, code += (C > 0) * 1
   asm("movb $0, %[out];"
     "cmpl $0, %[C];"
     "setg %%al;"
     "addb %%al, %[out];"
     "cmpl $0, %[B];"
     "setg %%al;"
     "shlb $1, %%al;"
     "addb %%al, %[out];"
     "cmpl $0, %[A];"
     "setg %%al;"
     "shlb $2, %%al;"
     "addb %%al, %[out];"
   : [out] "+dl" (code)
   : [A] "m" (A), [B] "m" (B), [C] "m" (C)
   : "%eax", "%edx");

  switch(code){
   ...
    //same old switch statement
   ...
  }
   return ret;
 }
```

interestingly (and quite vexingly) when I change the asm to;

```
   asm ("cmpl $0, %[C];"
     "setg %[out];"
     "cmpl $0, %[B];"
     "setg %%al;"
     "shlb $1, %%al;"
     "addb %%al, %[out];"
     "cmpl $0, %[A];"
     "setg %%al;"
     "shlb $2, %%al;"
     "addb %%al, %[out];"
   : [out] "+dl" (code)
   : [A] "m" (A), [B] "m" (B), [C] "m" (C)
   : "%eax", "%edx");
```

Which should do the same thing but in a shorter, sweeter way, the performance is the same because the compiler decides to introduce the %cl register like this;

```
 movzbl -0x5(%ebp),%eax // load 'code' into the register (not needed!)
 mov    %eax,%ecx   // load 'code' into ecx?
 cmpl   $0x0,0x10(%ebp) // compare 'C' and 0
 setg   %cl         // set byte for code imediately, skips zeroing 'code'
 cmpl   $0x0,0xc(%ebp)  // compare 'B' and 0
 setg   %al
 shl    %al         // set %al, then make it equal to two if not equal to zero
 add    %al,%cl     // add it to code
 cmpl   $0x0,0x8(%ebp)  // compare 'A' and 0
 setg   %al
 shl    $0x2,%al    // set %al, then make it equal to four if not equal to zero
 add    %al,%cl     // add it to code
 mov    %cl,-0x5(%ebp)  // move the final value back onto the stack
```

It should be noted that the compiler will use %dl if I ask it to use %cl, and vice versa. Obstinate machine does not seem to want it's record shattered.

Directly enforcing conditionals seems to be a good way to go, as this method is quite close to beating the compiler